# php curl not following location

Tags: php, curl

The site I am trying to access adds a query string at the end of the url, the query string is unique to the session ID. I am wanting to post to the correct url which has the query string on the end but it is just going to the base url.

```
$curlarr    = array(
              CURLOPT_URL   => "http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber",   
              CURLOPT_POST  =>  TRUE,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => urlencode($fields),
              CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber",
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE
            );

curl_setopt_array($curlconf,$curlarr);
$result = curl_exec($curlconf);
echo curl_getinfo($curlconf, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

the echo from curl_getinfo returns the base url: `"http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber"`

if you were to enter this base url into your browser it redirects you to: `http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber?execution=e1s1` and the first 1 (e1) increases each time there's a new session

Comment: What is `$fields` variable?

Comment: It's the string of the fields combined

Comment: Can you show its output (`var_dump`)?

Comment: string(93) "tapByTrackSearch:refSearch:refNumbers=42342424&tapByTrackSearch:refSearch:ref_submit_button=&"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first url redirects you to another one with a token, a variable sent by the server (var name : execution) ; you are supposed to use this variable for every future http request. Seems that it gonna be controlled each time, maybe in the aim of avoiding bot-browsing.

This is the first page :

```
#curl  http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber
<html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
<p>It's now at <a href="http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber?execution=e1s1">http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByRefNumber?execution=e1s1</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

You used CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, that's fine, but you also have to store the cookie (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR) and to use it for the next http request (with CURLOPT_COOKIE)

Actually, don't use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION anymore. You dont want to loose your cookie on the way. You can parse the first page, get the "execution=xxxx" and then use the cookie to go further.

Edit : sometimes, curl browsing can just be avoided by using a kindly provided API.

Comment: yeah I was looking into the cookies, I couldn't find which cookie they used and even if I did find it I wasn't sure how to use the cookie file, could you give an example?

Comment: You can store the cookie on your filesystem and use it : curl_setopt($curlconf, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');

Comment: We can find all cookie values in Chrome / Developer tools / Resources / Cookies

Comment: It might not be pertinent but did you check out this API ? Hoping it work for both business and personnal tracking  http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/tracking/trackingsummary.jsf

Comment: Is the link working for both business and individual ? if so, please accept if the answer has been useful, thanks. If not let's go further with the cookie stuff